# ASP.NET: How to create a search function just using a textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, textbox

I would like to have suggestions with regards to having a search function in my website. It will be to find the registered customers so that it will be easier for the admin to look for a specific customer.

Can you give sample code snippets so that I can accomplish this specific search function?

Thank you.

Here is my .aspx code

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" Width="218px" 
        ontextchanged="txtSearch_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" />
</p>
<div style="overflow-x:auto; width:1200px">
 <asp:GridView ID="gvCustomer" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" 
        Caption="Customer Profile" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceBM" 
        ForeColor="Black" onrowcommand="gvCustomer_RowCommand" 
        DataKeyNames="ApplicantUsername" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Branch" HeaderText="Branch" 
                SortExpression="Branch" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ApplicantUsername" HeaderText="Username" 
                SortExpression="ApplicantUsername" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="NoAFirstName" HeaderText="First Name" 
                SortExpression="NoAFirstName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="NoALastName" HeaderText="Last Name" 
                SortExpression="NoALastName" />
            <asp:ButtonField CommandName="View Profile" HeaderText="Customer Profile" 
                Text="View" />
            <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Edit" HeaderText="Customer Profile" Text="Edit" />
            <asp:ButtonField CommandName="View CR" HeaderText="Credit Report" Text="View" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceBM" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PFCIConnectionString %>" 


        SelectCommand="SELECT [ApplicantUsername], [Branch], [NoALastName], [NoAFirstName] FROM [CustomerRegistration] WHERE (([Branch] = @Branch) AND ([NoALastName] LIKE '%' + @NoALastName + '%'))">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="Branch" SessionField="ApplicantUsername" 
                Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearch" Name="NoALastName" 
                PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: I think you're going to have to put some more effort in yourself, and include in your question what you have tried, before you'll get any answers.  As it stands, this questions is way to broad (and probably opinion based too)

Comment: Looks like some one is ordering some code from a fast food chain.

Comment: Welcome! We're not a code-writing service.  See [faq]; [ask]

Comment: Umm sir Mr. Edge, If you want to hide, might as well Delete this. http://stackexchange.com/users/7291831/earl-jan-follosco
Mr. Earl Jan Follosco. How is it that you want to trash talk from a developers site and believing that you can hide from us. Lol. We might know where you are and find you but we are not savages so get a grip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't provide any code here and asked for the directions, so here you go. Lets assume your TextBox name is '`textBox1`' and there is some button beside it. On the click event of that button you should be querying your database for the customer names that matches the text inside your '`textBox1`'. The query which you would be using for your search would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerName LIKE "%" + textBox1.text + "%"; //Assuming the table name is Customers
```

This should return all the customers who has `textBox1.text` inside their name. Hope this would give you some insight on where to start from. Cheers,,

Comment: If they didn't provide code, don't answer it. You don't have to answer every question, and in fact you should *avoid* answering bad questions.